# Как настроить форматирование?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```py
print(f"Группы '{courses[id1]}' и '{courses[id2]}' продают: {', '.join(all_names_sorted)}")
```

После форматирования (сохранения):

```py
print(
f"Группы '{courses[id1]}' и '{courses[id2]}' продают: {', '.join(all_names_sorted)}"
)
```

Можно ли как-то исправить это? До этого работал в PyCharm и такого не замечал, но в VS Code очень странно работает форматирование. Так же, как пример, есть:

```
 print("123")
```

(с пробелом в начале, т.е. неправильно, и он не сработает, при форматировании в PyCharm он его сместит и всё гуд). Но в VS Code стандартное форматирование, которое идет в комплекте с Python, смещает, но Black Formatter ничего не делает.

Когда через <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> форматирую, вообще выдаёт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы определённая часть кода **не** форматировалась даже при включённом Black Formatter, можно воспользоваться комментариями `# fmt:off` и `# fmt:on`. Код между ними будет игнорироваться:

```py
# fmt:off
print(f"Группы '{courses[id1]}' и '{courses[id2]}' продают: {', '.join(all_names_sorted)}")
# fmt:on
```

Comment: Мне нужно, что-бы это на весь проект работало,а не только на одну строчку